# repeat elements of an array according to other array with the same length? like repelem for numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a built-in function or vectorized-efficient combination to repeat each element on an array `u` based on the element on an array `v`. It would be something like `repelem` of Matlab (with array inputs).

Example:

```
a = np.array([1, 5, 2])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4]) # be must have same length of a
print np.repelem(a, b)
```

[1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: `np.repeat`, `np.tile`

Comment: Thank you!!! np.repeat(a, b) is the solution @hpaulj. You can post the answer and I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repeat(a, repeats)` should do the job

```
In [21]: np.repeat(np.array([1,5,2]), np.array([2,3,4]))
Out[21]: array([1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```