# How can I create a List of values from a column in a dataframe, where each value from the column has to appear n times in the list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a dataframe and need to create a separate List with the values from a certain column.

However the different values from the column have to appear multiple times in the list, as specified in another column.

So one column has the values and one the amount of how often the value should appear in the list.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Explanation:

```
lista = [a, b, c, d]
listb = [1, 2, 3, 4]

listWanted = [a, b, b, c, c, c, d, d, d, d]
```

I tried making two separate lists, one with the amounts and one with the values, and multiplying them. However that multiplies the acutal number in the Lists.

Comment: You must provide an explicit example, your description is ambiguous.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  refer to the stackoverflow guidelines in providing a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does the list example make it clearer?

Comment: Using zip to create key/value pairs for a dictionary, then iterating: `[l for l, c in dict(zip(lista, listb)).items() for i in range(c)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [repeat elements of an array according to other array with the same length? like repelem for numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758529/repeat-elements-of-an-array-according-to-other-array-with-the-same-length-like)